# C# exclude numbers from a list in random generation

Tags: c#, random

I am making a tic tac toe game and I am making it to be unbeatable
but first I have to let the computer know the rules.

I'm stuck in a step that is => when it's the computer's turn and we have just started the game so no win case so it's up to the computer to generate a random number that will be the computer's choice ( the block where he mark X or O )
so I need it to generate a number from 1 to 9 but by excluding the already used blocks ( numbers ).

I tried doing that by making a list and adding a number every time the human player used a block but I can't find a way to use those numbers from the list as exclusion for the random choice of the computer.

Here is what I tried and thnx in advance:

```
    //random

    List<int> cas = new List<int>();
    if (c1 == true)
    {
        cas.Add(1);
    }
    if (c2 == true)
    {
        cas.Add(2);
    }
    if (c3 == true)
    {
        cas.Add(3);
    }
    if (c4 == true)
    {
        cas.Add(4);
    }
    if (c5 == true)
    {
        cas.Add(5);
    }
    if (c6 == true)
    {
        cas.Add(6);
    }
    if (c7 == true)
    {
        cas.Add(7);
    }
    if (c8 == true)
    {
        cas.Add(8);
    }
    if (c9 == true)
    {
        cas.Add(9);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < cas.Count; i++)
    {
        random_except_list(cas[]);
    }

public static int random_except_list(int[] x)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int result = r.Next(1, 9 - );

    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        if (result < x[i])
            return result;
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Approach it from a different direction. Do not let the random number generator (RNG) provide the number of the place itself. Rather start with how many free places are still on the game field. Then let the RNG generate a number in the interval `[0,NumberOfFreePlaces)`, which i call here `N`. The random result is the Nth _free_ place (note i wrote "Nth **free** place"; which is not the same as "Nth place") on your game field. (Go through/skip `N` free place, the next free place will be the "computers choice")

Comment: The routine i described in my first comment is always the same, no matter which turn. The only thing that changes from turn to turn is `NumberOfFreePlaces`. On the plus side, you don't need to exclude arbitrary numbers from the RNG results ;-)

Comment: To add to @elgonzo's good suggestion, you could use an array instead of a list for the 3 x 3 board, and mark the squares  (change the value  of the array element) when the user or the computer picks a square.  If you have 3 values (0 = empty, 1 = human, 2 = computer) you can even draw or print out the board.  When the random number is say 3, you find the third 0 value in the array.

Comment: @elgonzo i'm not a pro of C# so i'm still a biginner 
can you explain me the first comment plz 
thnx

Comment: where c1,c2,.. come from?.

Comment: @BPWdeveloper, what part of my 1st comment do you not understand?

Comment: Your code won't compile - can you post real code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets have possible places to use:

```
List<int> possible = Enumerable.Range(1,9).ToList(); // create a list and add 1-9
```

and used places:

```
List<int> used = new List<int>();
Random rnd = new Random();
```

Now everytime we generate a random number in the range of `possible` list count as index and remove it from there and move it to used:

```
int index = rnd.Next(0, possible.Count);
used.Add(possible[index]);
possible.RemoveAt(index);
```

for user its just enough to check if it exists in the used so the acceptable number should be:

```
!used.Any(x=> x== NumberUserHaveChosen)
```

So the first time the random number can be 0-8 (as possible.Count==9) and take from it at random index.
the second time the random number can be 0-7 (as possible.Count==8) and take from it at random index.
and so on... while the `possible.Count != 0`

**in this case there is no need to generate random numbers several times that finally it won't exist in our used List.**

Several years ago I was working on a Sudoku algorithm, and what I was trying to achieve was to generate a valid solved sudoku table in minimum time possible, i get to the conclusion that I should replace the algorithm that each time I generate a number I have to check some lists to make sure the number was not generated before, as count of numbers were increasing these comparisons would become more and more. for example when only the number 4 is remaining, I should generate random numbers till I get 4. so I used this approach and the result was amazing.

Comment: hey, your reply is very interesting and i'll try it as soon as possible  but there is one part i didn't really understand where it can be placed 
" for user its just enough to check if it exists in the used so the acceptable number should be (...) "
thnx :)

Comment: List.Any() returns a boolean value whether there is any items in the list that meets the condition inside any. having that `NumberUserHaveChosen` is the variable holding the place number that user have chosen (named it this way to be descriptive of what is it), `used.Any(x=> x== NumberUserHaveChosen)` mean that is there any item in the `used` list that is equal to `NumberUserHaveChosen`, and if true it means that the place is already used. having `!` before it (not found in the list) means that the place is empty and can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this:

```
   public static int random_except_list(List<int> x)
   {
        Random r = new Random();
        int result = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            result = r.Next(1, 10);
            if (!x.Contains(result))
                return result;                
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not a very good idea - what is the upper bound on the runtime for this to complete?

Comment: I was thinking that the range is very tiny.

Comment: True, but a quick test of 1000 runs after 7 moves had one run of 34 loop iterations, and it gets worst as the game progresses. With one move left, I got a run of 71 iterations.

Comment: @NetMage have a look at my answer.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani You may want to think about simplifying for a beginner (e.g. no LINQ). See my answer :)

Comment: you have Linq ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to use what you have written (more or less), but changing the method to take a `List<int>` which is what you are building, I would write the method using LINQ like this (except I would create a static `Random` variable and keep it between calls):

```
public static int random_except_list(List<int> x) => Enumerable.Range(1, 9).Where(n => !x.Contains(n)).ToList()[new Random().Next(0, 9 - x.Count)];
```

However, you can implement the same idea in a more explicit way using procedural code:

```
public static int random_except_list_explicit(List<int> x) {
    // First, generate a list of possible answers by skipping the except positions in x
    var possibles = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        if (!x.Contains(i))
            possibles.Add(i);

    // now pick a random member of the possible answers and return it
    return possibles[new Random().Next(0, possibles.Count)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is better to work with positions left. So user or computer select from all open positions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class app
{
    public static int random_except_list(List<int> openPositions)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int index = r.Next(openPositions.Count - 1);
        int result = openPositions[index];
        openPositions.RemoveAt(index);
        return result;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        List<int> openPositions = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            openPositions.Add(i);
        }

        bool turn = false;
        while (openPositions.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (int value in openPositions)
            {
                Console.Write(value + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            if (!turn)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Choose your Position");
                    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
                    int num = (int)key.KeyChar - 48;
                    if (openPositions.Contains(num))
                    {
                        openPositions.Remove(num);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        break;
                    }
                    else Console.Write(" is not Valid: ");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int compPos = random_except_list(openPositions);
                Console.WriteLine("Computer choose: " + compPos);
            }
            turn = !turn;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("No positions left");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```